# Expansion of a function in Spherical Harmonics

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, spherical-harmonics

Let $f$ be an even continuous function on the sphere $S^{n-1}$.

Find a spherical harmonic expansion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) of the function $f^n$.